# Slickgrid: aggregate at grouping row header

Tags: angular, slickgrid, angular-slickgrid

I'm trying to display the aggregates of sum at the same grouping row. Since I'm working with at least four group levels, the aggregate at the end seems a bit confusing (can be hard to distinguish), as you can see here in grey color.

[Image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmGa2.png)

I'm kinda newbie at all, so I'm stuck at what I can really do. Tried to replicate the type of Aggregate inside the formatter string, but it turns out a [Object].
I've found some few old topics with similar subject, but didn't work to me yet.

Thx

Comment: Please share the code that you've already worked with.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't display anything about grouping aggregation results (avg, sum, ...) in the header since the header has no such information. The only properties you can use are `value`, `count`, `level` and `groupingKey` which as you can see has no info about the aggregation. Also next time you ask a question, please post the code you tried.